# How do I go about implementing Android UI, specifically this gallery?

Tags: android

This question has 2 parts:

1) I'm new to Android development and find implementing the UI on Android quite overwhelming. It would be great help if you could point me to some free UI libraries or give me some advice on how mobile developers go about implementing the UI. Is there some framework of "standard" UI framework which I can use to build simple stuff that aren't directly possible from the Android API? I want to focus more on the content of the app rather than building all the quite common design patterns from scratch.

2) Currently, I'm building an app, which needs to have a gallery. I'm thinking of this

[image: Gallery design pattern]

I want to supply a `Vector` of `Photo` (which contains URL to the thumbnail and the actual sized image) to this `View` and get something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That app is simply displaying the photos in a gridview. There are many libraries out there but Nostro's Universal Image Loader supports adding images from urls into gridview. [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Thanks, I will use Nostro's library. Do you now any common UI libraries that developers use (not just for gallery).

Comment: Mainly I only know of ActionBarSherlock which provides ICS theming to unsupported devices

Comment: if this answer is right and helped you please mark as correct to help other people with the same problem find help

Comment: Thanks. I found this app - showcase of UI patterns, which I find quite useful. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns